# (PHP) Which is Better Between md5 with sha1

Tags: php

I have to register and login codes but is not equipped with the reset password.
Here the code is `sha1( _POST['password'])`

I use a script to reset the password is not in one package and it uses: `md5($_POST['password'])`

Well, in this case if one is not transformed into md5 or sha1 will generate an error.

I ask, which is better between the two, if there is a disability if you use the code?

Thank you..

Comment: Reading suggestions on that topic: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61087/what-are-the-enhancements-of-sha1-compared-to-md5 http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/is-sha1-better-than-md5-only-because-it-generates-a-hash-of-160-bits There are a lot more posts about why md5 is insecure and should not be used anymore for password hashing.

Comment: The good question is what is more secure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `password_hash` and `password_verify` for passwords in PHP 5 >= 5.5.0

As Charlotte mentioned in the comment, below 5.5 but >= 5.3 you can use [this](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)  lib.

Comment: For PHP 5.5 > x <= PHP 5.3, there is a compatibility pack on github.

Comment: means the page login.php and reset.php use the same code  `password_hash($_POST['password'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Both gives hash of string. md5()returns 32-character hexadecimal number where as sha1() returns 40-character hexadecimal number.There are many websites available where you can decrypt md5() and sha1() encrypted code.So i think, security is not depends on which function you used but how you use that function.for example try to first encrypt value by md5() and then encrypt by sha1() and decrypt vice-versa.

Comment: Those functions are not for encryption. Those 2 functions are for hashing.